# The controller with the name is not registered error in ui-router with lazyLoad

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement lazyload as follows but it throws below error:

> [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name
>   'BannerSettingsController' is not registered.

Here is my code:

```
.state('banner_settings', {
    url: '/banner_settings',
    views: {
        'header': { templateProvider: function($http, $stateParams, GetHeader) {
            return GetHeader.get().then(function(obj){
                   return $http.get(obj.templateName).then(function(tpl){
                          return tpl.data;
                   });      
                });
              }
        },
        'content': { 
                    templateUrl: "partials/banner_settings.html",
                    controller  : 'BannerSettingsController'
                },
        'footerCopyright': { templateUrl: 'partials/after_login/copyright.html' },
        'sidebar': { templateProvider: function($http, $stateParams, GetSidebar) {
            return GetSidebar.get().then(function(obj){
                   return $http.get(obj.templateName).then(function(tpl){
                          return tpl.data;
                   });      
                });
            }
        }
    },
    resolve: {
       loadMyFiles: function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                files: [
                    "app/controllers/BannerSettingsController.js"
                ]
            });
       }
    }

})
```

Comment: can you put your controller code?

Comment: vvApp.controller('BannerSettingsController', [ '$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout','FileUploader', 'dialogs','$rootScope','Data','toastr','userSession','Translation',
  function($scope, Upload, $timeout,FileUploader,dialogs,$rootScope,Data,toastr,userSession,Translation){
  
  console.log(banner controller);          
  
}]);